# Getting error while deleting the Record in the "investigation screen"

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Concept is: When I saved the particular record on the investigation screen that "investigationID" field should save in another screen called "Deviation report" (you can see the below images)

investigation screen image

[image]

deviation screen image("investigationID" field value storing)

[image]

But here, I'm facing the problem when I'm trying to delete the record on the investigation screen that particle "investigationID". The value should become a null on the screen of deviation screen (you can see above image ...> yellow colour marked of "deviation screen")

That related code:

I wrote the code in RowPersisted event (when it is saved this investigationID field should save in deviation screen (you can see in "deviation screen image"...> it is saving):

```
    protected void TSInvestigation_RowPersisted(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = (TSInvestigation)e.Row;
        if (row == null)
            return;

        if (row.InvestigationCD.Trim() != "<NEW>" /*row.InvestigationCD != null && TSInvestigationView.Cache.GetStatus(row) == PXEntryStatus.Inserted*/)
        {

            DeviationReportMaint DeviationReportMaintGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<DeviationReportMaint>();
            DeviationReportMaintGraph.Clear();

            //TSInvestigation get = this.TSInvestigationView.Current;

            //TSDeviationReport retbatch = DeviationReportMaintGraph.TSDeviationReportView.Insert(new TSDeviationReport());
            //TSDeviationReport retbatch = PXSelect<TSDeviationReport>.Select(DeviationReportMaintGraph);

            if (row.DeviationDocID != null /*&& get.InvestigationCD != null*/)
            {
                TSDeviationReport tSDeviation = PXSelect<TSDeviationReport, Where<TSDeviationReport.deviationCD,
                           Equal<Required<TSDeviationReport.deviationCD>>>>.Select(this, row.DeviationDocID);

                if (tSDeviation != null)
                {
                    tSDeviation.InvestigationID = row.InvestigationCD;
                    DeviationReportMaintGraph.TSDeviationReportView.Update(tSDeviation);
                    DeviationReportMaintGraph.Actions.PressSave();

                    //DeviationReportMaintGraph.TSDeviationReportView.Cache.Update(tSDeviation);
                    //DeviationReportMaintGraph.Actions.PressSave();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I wrote the code in RowDeleted event (When I delete the row on the investigation screen that related investigationcd field should become a null value on the "deviation screen" you can see in "deviation screen image")

```
    protected void TSInvestigation_RowDeleted(PXCache cache, PXRowDeletedEventArgs e)
    {

        var row = (TSInvestigation)e.Row;
        if (row == null)
            return;


        DeviationReportMaint DeviationReportMaintGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<DeviationReportMaint>();
        DeviationReportMaintGraph.Clear();

        //TSInvestigation get = this.TSInvestigationView.Current;

        if (row.DeviationDocID != null /*&& get.InvestigationCD != null*/)
        {
            TSDeviationReport tSDeviation = PXSelect<TSDeviationReport, Where<TSDeviationReport.deviationCD,
                   Equal<Required<TSDeviationReport.deviationCD>>>>.Select(this, row.DeviationDocID);

            if (tSDeviation != null /*|| tSDeviation == null*/)
            {
                tSDeviation.InvestigationID = null;

                DeviationReportMaintGraph.TSDeviationReportView.Update(tSDeviation);
                DeviationReportMaintGraph.Actions.PressSave();
            }
        }

    }
```

But while I'm deleting the record I'm getting this below error:

[image]

Getting this error while deleting the record on investigation screen

[image]

Where is the mistake in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You’re setting the wrong value in the `InvestigationID` field - it should be `row.InvestigationID`, not `row.InvestigationCD`